# Sometimes okhttp3 does not wait for a complete response from the server it only gets the header without the body

Tags: android, kotlin, flask, retrofit2, okhttp

here's the code for the retrofit2 instance :

```
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient

import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor


private const val BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:5000/"

class RetrofitInstance {
    companion object{
        private val retrofitInstance by lazy {
            val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
            val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .build()
            Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(client)
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
        }
        val retrofitService by lazy {
            retrofitInstance.create(PetitsGazouillisApiService::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

```
import ca.qc.cgodin.projet_final_amdroid.models.Jeton
import ca.qc.cgodin.projet_final_amdroid.models.Utilisateur
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Header
import retrofit2.http.Path

interface PetitsGazouillisApiService {
    @GET("api/jeton")
    suspend fun getJeton(@Header("Authorization") basicAuthorizationCredentials : String): Response<Jeton>

    @GET("api/jeton_user/{jeton}")
    suspend fun getUserWithJeton(@Path("jeton") jeton : String): Response<Utilisateur>
}
```

the localhost flask server receives the request :

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2021 20:42:04] "GET /api/jeton HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2021 20:42:04] "GET /api/jeton_user/glo57PjR7Bp2cAof3zQfuAHRT4wwotUc HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

but most of the time on the client side i receive only the header of the response:

```
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/jeton_user/glo57PjR7Bp2cAof3zQfuAHRT4wwotUc (8ms)
    Content-Type: application/json
    Content-Length: 53532
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Server: Werkzeug/2.0.1 Python/3.9.8
    Date: Thu, 18 Nov 2021 01:42:04 GMT
```

and rarely sometimes i receive the full response with the body
[Image of client side working correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqo3h.png)

with postman and curl I always receive the full answer

I am using an android emulator and i dont have an android phone to test it.

and finally when I dont receive the body i get this error which is normal because if i don't
receive the body the content-length in the header will never be the same size as body content-length

```
java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec$FixedLengthSource.read(Http1ExchangeCodec.java:430)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange$ResponseBodySource.read(Exchange.java:286)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.request(RealBufferedSource.java:72)
        at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:253)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:229)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:172)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Sorry for my bad english my main language is french and thank you if you can help me.

**EDIT**
my viewmodel

```
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import ca.qc.cgodin.projet_final_amdroid.models.Utilisateur
import ca.qc.cgodin.projet_final_amdroid.repository.PetitsGazouillisRepository
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.lang.Exception

class LoginViewModel : ViewModel(){
    val petitsGazouillisRepository = PetitsGazouillisRepository()
    val jeton: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
    val utilisateur: MutableLiveData<Utilisateur> = MutableLiveData()

    fun getJeton(basicAuthorizationCredentials: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            val response = petitsGazouillisRepository.getJeton(basicAuthorizationCredentials)
            jeton.postValue(response.body()?.jeton)
        }catch (e: Exception){
        }
    }

    fun getUserWithJeton(jeton : String) = viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            val response = petitsGazouillisRepository.getUserWithJeton(jeton)
            utilisateur.postValue(response.body())
        }catch (e: Exception){
        }
    }
}
```

Also when i remove the the avater string which is a base64image from the Utilisateur object I always get the response with the body. So maybe the problem is from the the size of the response body.

Comment: How many bytes is the response with curl?

Comment: the response have 53532 byte in curl

Comment: can you show where you are parsing response? using `interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.Basic`

Comment: with Level.BASIC the console returns : ```D/OkHttp: --> GET http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/jeton
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/jeton (109ms, 45-byte body)
D/OkHttp: --> GET http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/jeton_user/7LLyHAf4sBKAPtapMrPElmoAkwuDrOjJ
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/jeton_user/7LLyHAf4sBKAPtapMrPElmoAkwuDrOjJ (10ms, 53532-byte body)```

Comment: Just wondering, why need to load the image from base64 encoded string instead of URI? As base64 may impacting the payload size (base64 encoded string is larger than binary image) and the time for the response

Comment: I need to use a base64 encoded string because my server need to load user from a csv file that my teacher gave me for the assignment. Is there a way to make the client wait for the full response from server.